# Программно изменить значение выбранной строки dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы. В первой находится dataGridView, во второй в textBox передаются значения ячеек выбранной строки, который затем изменяет пользователь. Нужно перезаписать значения выбранной строки в dataGridView значениями, введёнными пользователем. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно связать эти формы, например сделать в форме с `TextBox` конструктор с параметром принимающим исходную форму с таблицей и запоминать ее как родителя.

   ```
   private TableForm parent; //родительская форма

   public TextForm(TableForm parent)
   {
       this.parent = parent;
       InitializeComponent();
   }
   ```
2. Для формы с таблицей  завести публичный метод который будет принимать новые значения.

   ```
   public void SendDataToGrid(params object[] data)
   {
     dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].SetValues(data);
     //Определяем индекс текущей строки, записываем в неё пришедшие значения 
   }
   ```
3. В форме с текстбоксами использовать полученный метод по необходимости, например так по клику для случая с одним `TextBox`

   ```
   private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       parent.SendDataToGrid(dataBox.Text);
   }
   ```